# NetLogo: matrix output to CSV

Tags: csv, matrix, netlogo

I would like to have matrix in CSV file as you can see below:

```
 - element11;element12;element13;element14
 - element21;element22;element23;element24
 - element31;element32;element33;element34
```

and so on.

I do not know how to force NetLogo to stop to write into rows of the first column and to go to the second, third and further columns.

Is there another possibility how to do output of matrix?

Comment: Have you looked at File Output Example, in the Code Examples section of the Models Library?

Comment: Yes, I have seen it, but there is no mention about matrices.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but something like the following should work.

```
let matlist matrix:to-row-list my-matrix
foreach matlist [
  foreach but-last ? [
    file-type ?
    file-type ","
    ]
  file-type last ?
  file-type "\n"
]
```

Comment: Thanks. You gave me point, where I did mistake. Output algorithm idea was good, but I did not realize that file-print prints each value into own row. This was the problem. With use of file-type it works as I wanted.